# How to remove duplicates in a numpy array and keep its sorting

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, duplicates

I have a list of numpy arrays and want to remove duplicates and also keep the order of my sorted data. This is my array with duplicates:

```
dup_arr=[np.array([[0., 10., 10.],\
                   [0., 2., 30.],\
                   [0., 3., 5.],\
                   [0., 3., 5.],\
                   [0., 3., 40.]]),\
         np.array([[0., -1., -4.],\
                   [0., -2., -3.],\
                   [0., -3., -5.],\
                   [0., -3., -6.],\
                   [0., -3., -6.]])]
```

I tried to do it using the following code:

```
clean_arr=[]
for i in dup_arr:
    new_array = [tuple(row) for row in i]
    uniques = np.unique(new_array, axis=0)
    clean_arr.append(uniques)
```

But the problem of this method is that it changes the sort of my data and I do not want to to sort them again because it is a tough task for my real data. I want to have the following result:

```
clean_arr=[np.array([[0., 10., 10.],\
                     [0., 2., 30.],\
                     [0., 3., 5.],\
                     [0., 3., 40.]]),\
           np.array([[0., -1., -4.],\
                     [0., -2., -3.],\
                     [0., -3., -5.],\
                     [0., -3., -6.]])]
```

But the code shuffle it. I also tried the foolowing for loops but it was not also successful because I can not iterate until the end of my data and stop the second for loop before reaching to the end of each array of my list.

```
clean_arr=[]
for arrays in dup_arr:
    for rows in range (len(arrays)-1):
        if np.all(arrays [rows]== arrays [rows+1]):
            continue
        else:
            dat= arrays [rows]
            clean_arr.append(dat)
```

In advance, I do appreciate any help and contribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use `np.unique` with `axis=0`. If you want to keep the order from the original sequence try this -

```
[i[np.sort(np.unique(i, axis=0, return_index=True)[1])] for i in dup_arr]
```

```
[array([[ 0., 10., 10.],
        [ 0.,  2., 30.],
        [ 0.,  3.,  5.],
        [ 0.,  3., 40.]]),
 array([[ 0., -1., -4.],
        [ 0., -2., -3.],
        [ 0., -3., -5.],
        [ 0., -3., -6.]])]
```

1. `np.unique(i, axis=0, return_index=True)[1]` returns the indexes of the unique elements.
2. `np.sort()` sorts these indexes back to original sequence in array.
3. `[f(i) for i in dup_arr]` applies the above 2 steps over each element in dup_arr.

**NOTE:** You will NOT be able to completely vectorize this operation (say by `np.stack` on this operations since it will may have variable duplicates removed from each matrix. This will cause the numpy array to have unequal shapes over an axis.

---

Breaking the steps as a function -

```
def f(a):
    indexes = np.unique(a, axis=0, return_index=True)[1]
    return a[np.sort(indexes)]

[f(i) for i in dup_arr]
```

Comment: Dear @Akshay Sehgal, Thanks for your time. I do appreciate your solution. But, the problem is that your solution ic changing the sorting of my initial array and I do not want to change it. I just want to remove duplicate rows and other rows should stay in their relative position. I mean they should not be shifted up or down.

Comment: Updated my answer do check and let me know if it solves it.

Comment: Changed this to a one liner after removing the 2nd list comprehension. You only need 1 here.

Comment: Dear @ Akshay Sehgal, Thanks again for being that much helpful. Maybe your post will be more informative if you keep also the functoin method. I hink you removed it in your last edit.

Comment: Sure adding that for more details

Answer (score 1):

In my humble opinion, every time you want to remove duplicates from an array or list in Python, you should consider using a set.

Also, try to avoid using multiple nested loops since errors easily occur and they're hard to find. I suggest you give the following code a try:

```
removed_duplicates=[]
    
for subarr in dup_arr:
    removed_duplicates.append(np.array([list(item) for item in set(tuple(row) for row in subarr)]))
```

Basically what's happening is that you convert your array to a tuple, then to a set that removes all duplicates, and then to a list. Since your original data had an array of np.arrays, your convert the list back to a np.array before you append it to the new array.

Would this work?

Comment: Dear @Erik Hallin, Thanks for your time. I do appreciate your solution. The problem is that my sorted array is changed by your solution and I want to keep the sorting of my initial array. I just want to delete the duplicates and do not touch the sorting.